# Filled up 100% of the width but <p> on newline doesn't centre align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a webpage with a box on the mainpage and it looks like this

```
Login
-----Or-----
Register
```

This is the code I have

```
<center>
   <p>Login</p>
    <hr style="width: 16%; float: left; margin-left:30%;"/>
     <p style="float: left; margin-left:2%; margin-right: 2%; width: 4%;">Or</p>
    <hr style="width: 16%; float: right; margin-right: 30%;"/>
   <p>Register</p>
</center>
```

It looks like this -

[image]

I have 1 problem and 1 thing I need help doing

The problem is the Register text is not aligned even though it should be and the thing I need help with is getting the < hr> lines to be half way down the Or text

Like this -

[image: Sorry for very bad image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: FYI the `<center>` tag was deprecated like 20 years ago.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: use CSS instead of <center>

Comment: if you like this dirty a simple `<p style="clear:both">Register</p>` would have sufficed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dDS8t/1)**.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Login</p>
    <div id="or"> <span>Or</span>
    </div>
    <p>Register</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
}
#or {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.5em;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Well, you'd obviously need to tweak the styling a bit, but with the picture alone I can't tell what needs to be changed. Would need to see the actual code.

Comment: Try changing the color of the span from `white` to `#eee` and the padding on the Register paragraph to `10px`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Login</p>
    <div class="hr"><p>or</p></div>
    <p>Register</p>
</div>

.foo{text-align:center;line-height:1em;}
.foo .hr p{background:#fff;margin:0;position:relative;z-index:2;display:inline-block;padding:0 1em;}
.foo .hr:after{border-bottom:1px solid #000;content: " ";display:block;position:relative;top:-0.5em;}
```

Should look like this:

[image]